# Azure query returning all rows when it shouldnt be iOS7 programming

Tags: ios, azure

So i query the database for all the rows with the account number i provide, yet it still displays all the rows from the database in the table view, regardless of what user i pass it.

I've looked over this for quite a while and i'm not quite sure why it isn't working, thanks in advance for any help!

```
MSTable *itemTable = [client tableWithName:@"Users"];
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"account=%@",activeAccount.userID];
NSLog(@"%@", queryString);  //this outputs "account=B51578B1-8A73-42BA-87B4-4F26E401222A" 
                            //which is correct
[itemTable readWithQueryString:queryString completion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error)
 {
     [self.usersArray removeAllObjects];
     for (NSDictionary *item in items)
     {
         User *user = [[User alloc]init];

         user.account = [item valueForKey:@"account"];
         user.name = [item valueForKey:@"name"];
         user.pay = [item valueForKey:@"pay"];
         user.job = [item valueForKey:@"job"];

         [self.usersArray addObject:user];
     }
     [self.tableView reloadData];
 }];
```

Comment: What's not working exactly?

Answer (score 0):

There must be some problem with the **primary key** 
this problem seems with how you store the data in table...
I want to say **RELATIONAL MODEL**  
else everything will work fine

Comment: something like that...
select * from table where account ="123";